# How to type annotate dict comprehension?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Mypy considers this to be valid with `strict = true`:

```py
from typing import Dict, TypeVar

KeyType = TypeVar("KeyType")
ValueType = TypeVar("ValueType")


class InvertibleDict(Dict[KeyType, ValueType]):
    def __inverse__(self) -> "InvertibleDict[ValueType, KeyType]":
        new_instance: "InvertibleDict[ValueType, KeyType]" = self.__class__()
        for key, value in self.items():
            new_instance[value] = key
        return new_instance
```

However, it does not accept the following, more concise version of the same code, saying that "Keywords must be strings" on the last line:

```py
from typing import Dict, TypeVar

KeyType = TypeVar("KeyType")
ValueType = TypeVar("ValueType")


class InvertibleDict(Dict[KeyType, ValueType]):
    def __inverse__(self) -> "InvertibleDict[ValueType, KeyType]":
        return self.__class__(**{value: key for key, value in self.items()})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MyPy is correct here, it is *catching a bug in your implementation* (the beauty of static type checking). The type of:

```
{value: key for key, value in self.items()}
```

Is `Dict[KeyType, ValueType]`, but *that will fail in general when you do:*

```
dict(**some_mapping)
```

Where the keys *are not guaranteed to be strings*.

Observe:

```
>>> dict(**{1:2,3:4})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: keywords must be strings
```

You just want:

```
return self.__class__({value: key for key, value in self.items()})
```

Which won't fail in general:

```
>>> dict({1:2,3:4})
{1: 2, 3: 4}
```

Personally, I would go with your first implementation regardless to not unnecessarily waste 2x the amount of space required, and do a needless second-pass.

Note, you would probably never use `**` unpacking to initialize a dict, the keyword-argument form of the constructor is a convenience for writing something like:

```
>>> dict(foo=1, bar=2)
{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}
```

You can even use this handy trick when copying a dictionary but wanting to force a value for particular string keys:

```
>>> dict({'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}, bar=42)
{'foo': 1, 'bar': 42}
```

Comment: Good point about the second pass, which I had not considered. This is exercise code, not production code, so clarity is most important, but I think I might go with this in any case. I'm not sure I understand why `dict({1:2,3:4})` works and `dict(**{1:2,3:4})` fails though.

Comment: @l0b0 because it is a *specialized form of the constructor* meant to work only with string keys. For whatever reason, it was designed to reject non-string keys when you use `**kwargs`, perhaps for consistency who knows. Again, you would really never do `dict(**some_other_dict)`, normally, to copy a built-in container you would just do `ContainerType(container_instance)`, e.g. `list(some_list)`, `set(some_set)`, `dict(some_dict)`....

Comment: Interesting, thanks! [Implementation](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/mypy-exercises/-/merge_requests/27) for reference.

Comment: @l0b0 anyway, I don't think you gain any *clarity* by using the list comprehension. Concise isn't synonymous with clarity. That loop is about as clear and pythonic as it gets. I would just use `type(self)` but `self.__class__` is accetable

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I prefer `self.__class__()` to `type(self)()`, but it's good to know about alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Just for laughs I tried `return self.__class__({value: key for key, value in self.items()})`, which seems to work the same and passes `mypy` checks. TIL `dict`s can be initialised with a dict rather than `**kwargs`.